# Use jQuery functions with dynamically loaded div's

Tags: jquery, json, function, onclick

So I have a problem I can't really figure out. I dynamically load divs through JSON into my webpage. However, I can't figure out how to use the jQuery onclick function with each div. Thanks.

Comment: Delegated events, there is thousand off topic about that on SO.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: All the information you need is here : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @PSL probably jquery dynamic element events question should be banned now... myself might have answered 50+ I think